# Executing methods in a running secondary thread. Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have some methods that need to be run from the same secondary thread (if the thread is different they don't work). I have the secondary thread running. Is it possible to execute these methods from this secondary running thread by invoking them from outside? I got good results extracting the content of the methods and putting it in a "state machine" inside the "run" method, but my question is if I have any other way to do this without extracting the content of the method and easier and cleaner.

Example:

```
package threadapp;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

public class ThreadApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Utils utils = new Utils();
    }
}

class Utils {

    JFrame frame;
    JButton btn1;

    public Utils() {
        btn1 = new JButton("btn1");
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 200);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(btn1);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        t1.setName("Thread that I need to use when press button");
        t1.start();

        btn1.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            execute = true;
        });
    }
    
    public void ExecuteActionInTheSameSecondaryThread(){
        // Large method to execute withowt extrac the content
    }
    
    ///// It works!!! Content of the method//////
    boolean execute = false;    
    ////////////////////////

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                
                ///// It works!!! //////
                if (execute) {
                    execute = false;
                    System.out.println("Button pressed in: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }   
                ////////////////////////
                
                try {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Utils.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Once a thread is running, it decides itself what it does: it executes the run() method. If you want to give it a task from the outside, you have to write a run() method that looks for tasks from the outside, e.g. by reading something from a queue.

Comment: Use custom thread pool executors and assign tasks to specific pool, this way you can handle which pool will work on which task.